# What should we do about broken Tex math markup in postings?

Tags: discussion, style, markdown

What should be done about postings that contain embedded <sub><sub><sub>[image: LaTeX]</sub></sub></sub> math markup in them?

Certainly we should not ask for that to be enabled; its cost is much too high!

Should we replace them with images with the markup evaluated so that the text can finally be read?  To show how nasty it looks, here are example postings with this problem: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/205969/2085), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/205969/2085), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/120237/2085), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/144576/2085), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26643/2085). So instead of this sort of garbage:

> The square root of the matrix $A$, denoted by $\sqrt{A}$, is well-defined.

It could be replaced with this image:

[image: replacement image for previous text]

Sometimes this can be done with Unicode so that it can be left as text, but unfortunately, Georgia is not well disposed towards the needed combining characters.  For example:

> The square root of the matrix , denoted by √̅, is well-deﬁned.

At least on my computer, it does not correctly join up the overline to the radical sign, and so is inferior to the image replacement.

However, image replacement is a pain to make look good — I have not tried to do so here. I just think these math-markup bits look ridiculous, and that we should do something to improve them.

I’m not quite sure what, though.

Comment: Your links [1] and [2] are identical.

Comment: I wonder if there is scope to enable it on a per-post basis: if a page needs it, it's injected *for that page*, but it doesn't need to be loaded in every page on the site.

Comment: Image replacement would also be a hassle for accessibility. I think @Andrew's suggestion for enabling it on a per-post basis is a sensible one, but I don't know if it's possible in SE at the moment.

Comment: If it's ongoing, can we change the interface to use mathjax?

Comment: "its cost is much too high": is that really the case? The cost to who? The SE developers? To the machines processing the posts? To the users?

Comment: &sqrt; $sqrt; @sqrt;

Comment: @Mitch It makes pages take longer to load even if there isn't any math being rendered. I can't find the [meta.se] post on this at the moment, but it was something like a 20% increase in page load times, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Enabling MathJax

As a moderator on Code Review who helped to push for MathJax to be activated there, I can say that the current Stack Exchange policy makes you work hard to justify it.  [Performance is a Feature](http://blog.codinghorror.com/performance-is-a-feature/), and [Speed Still Matters](http://blog.codinghorror.com/speed-still-matters/), says Jeff Atwood, so they want pages to render quickly.  MathJax is enabled per site, not per question, so they are [reluctant to incur the performance overhead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252283/1157100) of loading and executing the MathJax code if it is deemed non-essential to the site.

To request MathJax to be activated, the community needs to come up with a list of posts that would have [benefitted "*extensively*"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/mathjax-on-codereview#comment4244_1443) from MathJax.  That is a tough request to fulfill for EL&U.  (Code Review had to work hard to convince SE, and we sometimes deal extensively with mathematical notation.)

### Making do without MathJax

For the most part, it is possible to convey basic mathematical notation with a combination of Unicode, ASCII art, and, as a last resort, images.  One way to make an image is to use [latex2png](http://latex2png.com).

### Specific posts

I've gone ahead and typeset the specific posts mentioned here using Unicode.

Comment: One thing that has consistently been a problem with performance is loading the javascript in the head versus the footer.